# I have Wordpress installed in the webroot directory of my CakePHP application so that my site has a blog. Am I at risk?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

Since the files are in webroot, I'm concerned I'm exposing private information  (db config stuff perhaps, I'm not sure because I haven't looked through he wordpress files). If so, how do I set it up so that people don't have access to those files?

Thank you very much

W

Comment: It's Wordpress - of course you're at risk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what this has to do with CakePHP.

Anyway, regardless of where you install WordPress, it's a good idea to secure it. The WordPress codex has a very nice guide to [hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) that you will be interested in reading.

Comment: It has to do with cakephp because it's in the cake webroot directory.  I thought there might be a cake way to deny access to a specific folder.

Comment: Are you asking about securing WordPress, then, or your CakePHP app?

Comment: securing wordpress I guess.  There's db information and stuff in there

Comment: The contents of the wp-config.php file won't be readable to the world unless you've horribly misconfigured your server. So no big deal there. Just make sure you've reasonably secured your server so that it can't be gotten by other (malicious) means. See the link I posted in this very answer.

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed to hear...I'll take a look at that link.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the correct permissions to configuration files? For example in UNIX-like systems you may use chmod command for that.